# Remove the administratorLogin of the SQL server resource

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-bicep, paas

Our goal is to not have the SQL server login created, or remove it at a later stage in an automated way, if possible.

Currently, we have the Bicep code:

```
resource sqlServer 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2021-02-01-preview' = {
name: serverName 
location: location
properties: {
  administratorLogin: administratorUsername
  administratorLoginPassword: administratorPassword
  minimalTlsVersion: '1.2'
  publicNetworkAccess: publicNetworkAccess
  restrictOutboundNetworkAccess: restrictOutboundNetwork
  version: '12.0'
}
}
```

The property values are provided by parameters. For example, for the value of administrator login, we set something like 'admin'.

That SQL user is not something we use, as we use an automated workflow (using AZ CLI) to change the 'administratorType' to 'ActiveDirectory', during the provisioning of this resource.

However, by using this approach, the 'admin' login is still created.

We would like to use Azure AD Only Authentication. And for the login, we would like to set it to a group inside an Administrative Unit.
The reason why we didn't specify this in the Bicep code, is that we don't have the SID (object ID) of that group as it has not been created yet (as it will happen later in our automated workflows).
Have considered using 'Get-AzureADGroup' cmdlet via deployment script resource,
so that we can get the SID of that security group. But this approach seems to automatically deploy additional resources which is denied by our internal policy.

We are now trying the following code:

```
resource sqlServer 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2022-05-01-preview' = {
  name: serverName 
  location: location
  properties: {
    administrators: {
      administratorType: 'ActiveDirectory'
      azureADOnlyAuthentication: true
      login: serverExternalAdminostratorLoginExisting
      principalType: 'Group'
      sid: serverExternalAdministratorSidExisting
    }
    minimalTlsVersion: '1.2'
    publicNetworkAccess: publicNetworkAccess
    restrictOutboundNetworkAccess: restrictOutboundNetwork
    version: '12.0'
  }
}
```

We are not even using the property 'administratorLogin'. But it seems that a default login user is created.
By looking at the template after the resource is created on Azure, we see the following:

```
"properties": {
                "administratorLogin": "CloudSAb7d51d5b",
                "version": "12.0",
                "minimalTlsVersion": "1.2",
                "publicNetworkAccess": "Enabled",
                "administrators": {
                    "administratorType": "ActiveDirectory",
                    "principalType": "Group",
                    "login": "admin_s704sql084",
                    "sid": "dfa109eb-****-41cb-****-ea8c69093534",
                    "tenantId": "3aa4a235-****-48d5-****-7fcf05b459b0",
                    "azureADOnlyAuthentication": true
                },
                "restrictOutboundNetworkAccess": "Enabled"
            }
```

How do we get rid of that 'CloudSA********' user? Could not find any documentation/information of this user.
If possible, we would do that using code, to get this automated.

Comment: I imagine it s a default/required login => can you check if the login is enable on the sql server ?

Comment: Hi @Thomas, yes, it looks like that it is a default login. And it seems that it is enabled.
By looking at the view 'sys.sql_logins', the column 'is_disbaled' has value of 0.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the `AdministratorLogin` property explicitly as an `empty string ('')` when defining the SQL Server resource. @KWC

Comment: @Jahnavi, I just tried to set 'AdministratorLogin' property to an empty string. But then the deployment fails because it also requires the 'AdministratorLoginPassword' property. Also tried to set that one to an empty string. The deployment fails due to an invalid value was given for the password parameter.

Comment: You can also try in this way. Remove administrator login and password. Because if you want to use AzureAD only authentication, there is no need of providing these login and passwords. Have you tried that way? @KWC

Comment: @Jahnavi, yes, I have tried that. The result was the 'administratorLogin' property was automatically added. And the username that starts with 'cloudsa' was set as server admin, which can be seen in the Azure portal. I could not see any documentation about this user. Guess that this one is not possible to remove/exclude?

Comment: Removing user and password details should work. Can you refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77717147/sql-deployment-bicep-ms-entra-group/77726497#77726497) once. @KWC

Comment: @Jahnavi, yes, it works. But if you look into the template for the deployed resource in the Azure portal, the property 'administratorLogin' was added automatically. The value was 'CloudSAxxxxxxxx'. Is this mandatory? Where can we find more information about this user? Who has the password of this auto-generated SQL login?

Comment: to be honest, if you specify azureADOnlyAuthentication: true that should be fine. you should ask MS on github to confirm

Comment: Thank you for the help. We have been in contact with Microsoft and got it confirmed. It is not possible to exclude the auto-generated SQL login (CloudSA********).

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can try specifying the `AdministratorLogin` property explicitly as an `empty string ('')` while defining the SQL Server resource.

By changing it like this, it will rely on only `Azure AD` authentication with the given specified group.

*Your Modified bicep code looks like below:*

```bash
resource sqlServer 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2022-05-01-preview' = {
  name: serverName 
  location: location
  properties: {
    administratorLogin: ''
    administrators: {
      administratorType: 'ActiveDirectory'
      azureADOnlyAuthentication: true
      login: serverExternalAdminostratorLoginExisting
      principalType: 'Group'
      sid: serverExternalAdministratorSidExisting
    }
    minimalTlsVersion: '1.2'
    publicNetworkAccess: publicNetworkAccess
    restrictOutboundNetworkAccess: restrictOutboundNetwork
    version: '12.0'
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not work, because when setting this property, it also requires the property 'administratorLoginPassword' to be set. Otherwise the deployment will fail.

Comment: Which one you are talking about? @KWC

Comment: The one (administratorLogin) that you added within the properties block.

Comment: Can you [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73305643/how-to-get-azure-ad-group-in-bicep-to-create-sql-server-with-azureadonlyauthenti) this as well. @KWC

Comment: I tried tried the example from you link.  For some weird reasons, it did not work even though I checked that the AAD group name and AAD group SID are correct. It gave me the error: 
> DeploymentFailed: The resource write operation failed to complete successfully, because it reached terminal provisioning state 'Failed'. Invalid value given for parameter Login. Specify a valid parameter value.

Comment: I added the azureADOnlyAuthentication and set it to true. Then the deployment works without the need to specify the 'administratorLogin' and 'administratorLoginPassword' properties.  However, the property 'administratorLogin' was automatically added with the value 'CloudSA********'.

Comment: Delete the existing bicep and create a new one and deploy again. May be the user details are stored in the backend. Can you try once? @KWC

Comment: we do deploy new resources for every test we make.